# Action<T> vs Standard Return

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm not a C# guy I'm more an Objective-C guy but lately I've seen a lot of implementations of:

```
public void Method(Action<ReturnType> callback, params...)
```

Instead of:

```
public ReturnType Method(params...)
```

One of the examples of this is the MVVM Light Framework, there the developer implements the data service contract (and implementation) using the first approach, so my question is: Why this? Is just a matter of likes or is the first approach asyncronous by defaut (given the function pointer). If that's true, is the standard return death? I ask cause I personally like the second approach is more clear to me when I see an API.

Comment: In case you haven't run across it already, with the Task Parallel Library, libraries offering async methods would *typically* offer Task<ReturnType> Method(params...) instead of taking a callback, but that may not be an option for libraries that need to work with frameworks that don't have Task<T> support (for instance, Silverlight got Task<T> added in version 5, so anything Silverlight 4 or before would need to stick with callbacks or some other pattern)

Comment: @JamesManning I've seen implementations of the TPL that looks pretty much clear. Are they -behind the covers- the same?

Comment: I think that would depend on whatever the implementing library is.  Conceptually, the TPL is a little 'better' (IMHO) because it handles things like cancellations and exceptions.  With the new language features, you can also write what 'feels' like synchronous code using the await keyword, which lets you avoid having to write callback methods, letting the compiler rewrite the method to do so for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike the API returning `ReturnType`, a version with callback can return right away, and perform the callback later. This may be important when the value to return is not immediately available, and getting it entails a considerable delay. For example, and API that requests the data from a web service may take considerable time. When the result data is not required to proceed, you could initiate a call, and provide an asynchronous callback. This way the caller would be able to proceed right away, and process notifications when they become available.

Consider an API that takes a URL of an image, and returns an in-memory representation of the image. If your API is

```
Image GetImage(URL url)
```

and your users need to pull ten images, they would either need to wait for each image to finish loading before requesting the next one, or start multiple threads explicitly.

On the other hand, if your API is

```
void Method(Action<Image> callback, URL url)
```

then the users of your API would initiate all ten requests at the same time, and display the images as they become available asynchronously. This approach greatly simplifies the thread programming the users are required to do.

Comment: Do you know any equivalent in Java?

Comment: @dantuch Java doesn't have delegates, so there is no direct equivalent. But you can do something similar using an interface with a single method. And you could then use anonymous class to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

The first method is likely to be an asynchronous method, where the method returns immediately and the callback is called once the operation has finished.

The second method is the standard way of doing method returns for (synchronous) methods in C#.

Of course, API designers are free to make whatever signature they seem fit; and there might be other underlying details to justify the callback style. But, as a rule of thumb, if you see the callback style, expect the method to be asynchronus.